# Joining inner members inside a list of objects in Python

Tags: python

I have the following array:

```
[
  {"Name": "abc", "Age": 10},
  {"Name": "xyz", "Age": 12},  
  {"Name": "def", "Age": 15}
]
```

I want to create the following array out of it:

```
["abc","xyz","def"]
```

ie just take the name field out of each object. Is there an easier way to do it other than through a loop?

Comment: As you can see by others two answer NO `way to do it other than through a loop`, because you have a `list` of  `dict`, and you need to get items inside the dicts.

Comment: What's not easy about a simple loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an error in the dictionary syntax, I'm assuming you wanted to use string keys.

The issue could be solved using list comprehensions:

```
data = [
  {'Name': 'abc', 'Age': 10},
  {'Name': 'xyz', 'Age': 12},
  {'Name': 'def', 'Age': 15}
]

print([item['Name'] for item in data]) #=> ['abc', 'xyz', 'def']
```

You could use `map` to avoid using loops, but it's not pythonic:

```
map(lambda i: i['Name'], data)
```

Comment: Fixed the dictionary syntax in the question. I was thinking of the map version. But if it is not pythonic, then I guess I will go with the loop approach. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a single line list comprehension:

```
d = [
  {"Name": "abc", "Age": 10},
  {"Name": "xyz", "Age": 12},  
  {"Name": "def", "Age": 15}
]

data = [i["Name"] for i in d]
```

Output:

```
['abc', 'xyz', 'def']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
your_nested_list = [
  {Name: "abc", Age: 10},
  {Name: "xyz", Age: 12},  
  {Name: "def", Age: 15}
]


result = []
for dict in your_nested_list:
    result.append(dict[Name])
```

In this code you iterate over dictionaries in your nested list and append values of thekey `Name`.

Answer (score 0):

Without a loop - but *you need to know in advance* the *number of your dictionaries* in your list and be sure that in *every of them is the key* `Name`:

```
your_nested_list = [
  {Name: "abc", Age: 10},
  {Name: "xyz", Age: 12},  
  {Name: "def", Age: 15}
]

result = [
    your_nested_list[0][Name], 
    your_nested_list[1][Name], 
    your_nested_list[2][Name],
    ]
```

Ugly enough, isn't it?